# how to add "google-play-services_lib" (google map V2) as a apk lib depedency

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services

I Need to use the Google Maps Android API v2 to in my android application, I'm using maven to handle my dependencies and build process,

I did follow this tutorial to set up the API V2 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

My Questions is how do i add "google-play-services_lib" as a dependency to my project (like a apkLib)

Sam.

Comment: Did you try this? https://github.com/JakeWharton/gms-mvn-install

Comment: I'm using windows,there is no windows installer in that package, do i need to use Cygwin to install this?

Comment: I'Installed the Cygwin and run the sh file, I got the following error " ./gms-mvn-install.sh
./gms-mvn-install.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
: invalid optionl.sh: line 3: set: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
./gms-mvn-install.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
./gms-mvn-install.sh: line 94: syntax error: unexpected end of file
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

and add the following dependency to the pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>5</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>5</version>
  <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```